# Network timeouts when running lengthy shiny apps

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-server

I have a shiny app which selects a subset of observations from a large dataframe, and then renders r markdown reports against each observation of that subset, zipping them all these reports at the end and downloading the zip file.

When the subset is small (eg less than 10 reports), all works fine, but a network timeout occurs once it takes more than a certain amount of time to render all the reports in the background (eg in some cases more than 100 reports need to be rendered).

I have tried editing the config file to set `app_init_timeout = 3600` and `app_idle_timeout =3600` but this does not seem to impact this problem....

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your app running locally, on a server, or on something like shinyapps.io?

Comment: Its actually running on an AWS instance of Shiny.

Comment: AWS = Amazon Web Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by separating the report creation from the download.  I used eventReactive to handle the report creation and the zipping of the files, and then made the downloadHandler conditional on the existence of the zip file, so that it only appeared when the downloaded file was ready.